# jQuery output after php check

Tags: php, jquery

Hi again here to ask you for a problem solved in first part on my first question.
i've a form that submit data via jQuery to a php page, the code:

```
var messaggio = $("input[name='messaggio']").val();
$.ajax({
   url:"js/php/sendchat.php",
   data:"messaggio="+messaggio,
   type:"post",
   success:function(data){
      $("input[name='messaggio']").val("");
      $("body").html(data);
   }
});
```

When i check send via jQuery, there's no output, and I still cannot understand why.
Here's my php:

```
$Msg=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['messaggio']));
if(substr($Msg,0,1 == "§")){echo $Msg;}
```

The output didn't show §Test that's the thing I wrote on input form, i think that this have not sense.
Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't close `substr`

```
if( substr($Msg, 0, 1) == "§" ) {
     echo $Msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` only works if you have a connection open to the database, or if it can open one. Assuming that is your whole code, it's probable you do not have such a connection, so it is returning false.

Comment: I checked the open connection path is correct and i tried to delete mysql_real_escape_string() :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using mb_string accuratly.